# What are the valid alignment values for std::align_val_t for C++ allocators?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocation

Now that C++ has several additional new and delete operators with std::align_val_t parameters, what are the valid values for them?

Are they 1, 2, 4, 8, ... and so forth?

Is there an upper limit to the values?

Defined by the compiler?

Comment: I'd expect the values be the same as those for [`alingas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)

Comment: @StoryTeller Is there a section of the C++ Standard which says they must be identical to alignas? What makes you expect them to be the same?

Comment: Well, the similar purpose, for one.

Comment: And yes, that standard specified at length what is valid alignment. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`std::align_val_t` and its constraints are specified in the synopsis of the language support header `<new>`. So if one reads [[new.delete]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/support.dynamic#new.delete-1) it says the following:

> Except where otherwise specified, the provisions of
>   [basic.stc.dynamic] apply to the library versions of operator new and
>   operator delete. **If the value of an alignment argument passed to any
>   of these functions is not a valid alignment value, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

So you must pass a value that is valid, where the definition of valid alignment is given at [[basic.align]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.align#4):

> Alignments are represented as values of the type std​::​size_­t. Valid
>   alignments include only those values returned by an alignof expression
>   for the fundamental types plus an additional implementation-defined
>   set of values, which may be empty. Every alignment value shall be a
>   non-negative integral power of two.

So yes, only powers of two plus any value your implementation explicitly allows. And don't worry about the mention of `std::size_t` above. `std::align_val_t` is simply an enum class with `std::size_t` as underlying type:

```
enum class align_val_t : size_t {};
```

This also implies the upper bound you asked about, essentially `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`. But of course your implementation may enforce a lower one.

Comment: Thanks. That's good as far as it goes. Can you answer the other part of my question? What is the upper value for supported alignments?

Comment: @LincolnMan - The only bound seems to be `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`.